# Filter using PrimeFaces menu bar

Tags: primefaces

Is there a possibility to filter data from a JSF rich dataTable(where I use composite attributes) when using a navbar like this in page home.xhtml:

```
     <p:menubar>
                <p:submenu label="Categories">
                    <p:submenu label="ANTIQUES">
                        <p:menuitem value="European Antiques"></p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem value="Asian Antiques"></p:menuitem>
                    </p:submenu>
               </p:submenu>
    </p:menubar>
```

I want to update the table's values based on the selected item(the selected items are categories from the table). The problem is that the table is in another page(listAuctions.xhtml):

```
<h:form id="form">
        <rich:dataTable id="auctionsTable" rows="7" value="#{cc.attrs.auctions}" var="auct" border="1" styleClass="flat list auctions" rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered and not empty cc.attrs.auctions}" filterVar="filterValue" rowClasses="odd-row, even-row">


            <rich:column sortBy="#{auct.name}" sortOrder="ascending" >
                <h:commandLink value="#{auct.name}" action="#{auctionManager.goToDetailsEnglish()}" rendered="#{auct.auctionTypes eq 'ENGLISH'}">
                    <f:param  name="auctionId" value="#{auct.id}"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink value="#{auct.name}" action="#{auctionManager.goToDetailsDutch()}" rendered="#{auct.auctionTypes eq 'DUTCH'}">
                    <f:param  name="auctionId" value="#{auct.id}"/>
                </h:commandLink>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column sortBy="#{auct.category}"
                     filterExpression="#{empty filterValue or fn:startsWith(auct.category, filterValue)}"
                     filterValue="#{filterBean.category}">
                    <f:facet name="header">CATEGORY</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{auct.category}"/>
                 </rich:column>
```

...

```
Those 2 pages are connected in whe welcome file like this:

<ui:composition template="templates/home.xhtml">
<ui:param name="activeTab" value="list" />

<ui:define name="content">
    <h2>Auction List</h2>
    <a:listAuctions auctions="#{auctionManager.all}"/>
</ui:define>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware you are mixing primefaces with richfaces and they don't work together?

Comment: OK. I will the make the table to be from primeFaces. But how should I connect then the submenu with the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `<p:menuItem onclick="PF('dataTableWidgetVarName').filter()" />`

And add widgetVar to your datatable: `<p:dataTable widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVarName" ... />`

Comment: OK. thanks.. but I really have one more curiosity: can I have the menubar in home page and the dataTable in another page(page that is connected with home page through composition) ?.. I don't know how to connect in this situation the 'dataTableWisgetVarName'.. because it's the same, but in different locations

Comment: If you mean by connect, using a template file then yes for sure it is possible. Maybe you can post code of all relevant pages?